# C++ Builder DrawGrid usage

Tags: c++builder-6

I am currently working on a Tetris Game in C++ Builder, using a DrawGrid.
I have already implemented the classes for the game and the pieces movement in
the DrawGrid. But I have no idea how to implement now the collision of 2 pieces.
Does anyone know how should I do that? 
I will post here some code if you ask me to do that.

Thankss!!

Comment: There is no way anyone can answer this, as we can't see how you are tracking the tiles relative to the grid. But, if you have a way to determine which grid cells a tile occupies, it should not be hard to check if another tile in your list occupies any of the same cells.

Comment: The problem is that I do not know which grid cells a tile occupies :))

Comment: then how do you know which cells a given tile needs to be drawn in at any moment?